# /boot partition out of free space on standard install of 13.04

Tags: boot, 13.04, updates, encryption, software-updater

[image]

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 a few weeks ago as a fresh install on my laptop. 64 bit, using full disc encryption.

Suddenly this message appears when updating the software.

I looked in GParted, and sure enough there is a separate partition with /boot on, which is only 243MiB. This is the **first partition**, on the drive - all following space is used by the encrypted filespace, which to me means that simply giving the /boot partition more space would be a tough task...

Here's a screenshot of my partitions. Note that this is unaltered from the standard automatic install setup... the only thing I did differently is choose to use full disc encryption.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `apt-get autoremove` and see if that removes some of the older kernel packages.

If that does not work, I would suggest you do what I've had to do before, find the kernel you're on now, that's working fine, then use `apt-get purge <name_of_older_kernel_package>` on the packages for the older kernels.

This will remove all of those older kernels that you are not booting to any longer and may no longer be needed.